Braking resistor getting hot due to constant DC voltage on terminals PBe and PB on ATV320
The drive is used in hosting application and I set the hoisting per-configured macro at commissioning,
But once I power on the drive and it is at RDY state the resistor gets very hot after few minutes.
I changed the drive with a new one but I'm getting the same behavior.
What am I missing here ?
Isn't it supposed to get supply when the DC bus gets over certain level in my case 780V ?

Have you considered asking the manufacturer of the drive? This a site intended for electronic design; not product support.

sorry, I did but I got no replies there

Well it seems the wiring is incorrect. Or, you have the resistor hooked up across the DC bus. You need to find the two proper terminals in which there is no voltage across the terminals when the motor is stopped.

You should be able to monitor this in the SoMove application in "online mode".

it's not connected to the dc bus, this is what driving me crazy

Low power 3 phase drives normally rectify the AC supply and filter with capacitors to get DC voltage for the output bridge (IGBT) for the motor. Capacitors bank are usually in serial groups and have a center point with resistors to balance. Depends of manufacturer, some drives connect this central point to ground, or have an optional terminal for this function.
In applications with regenerative working, as the diode rectifier cannot manage the DC overvoltage, there is a IGBT to drop DC bus with an internal or external resistor. The voltage level to switch this braking unit is usually ajusted by parameter.

Assuming the drives and parameters are Ok, if the resistor is heating without moving the motor, the problem should be in the AC supply. Check AC voltage peak, because one reason could be high harmonic grid. See simulation with 5th components of 100 Vp added to main grid of 400 V, Dc bus will rise to about 800 V, forcing breaking unit to switch on.

Although improbably,  I also found a similar case in job with the following setting: VFD with central capacitor bank connected to ground + grid ground earth very bad + ground fault in one phase. This will cause that voltage to ground of 2 phases to rise up to 400 V, and once you rectify you will get very high DC bus voltage, see simulation.


this is most likely it, I will connect my power analyzer and will post the results here once I get it, thank you for the detailed answer much appreciated !!

@RootOfMinusOne: to check the second possibity is very simple, measure the 3 phases to ground.  Also to be sure no voltage is coming from field, do all the tests with the output terminals disconnected.
